# Who understands Chewbacca?

Tags: star-wars, languages, chewbacca

Obviously, Han understands Chewbacca (almost) perfectly.  In the prequel trilogy, Yoda seems to understand him too.  In at least one scene in the original trilogy, C-3PO also understands Chewie, which is logical, since - as a protocol droid - translation is one of 3PO's primary functions.

> THREEPIO:  Captain Solo, this time you have 
>   gone too far.
>
> (Chewie growls)
>
> THREEPIO:  No, I will not be quiet, Chewbacca. 
>   Why doesn't anyone listen to me?

### Does anyone else in the *Star Wars* movies understand Chewbacca?

Comment: This might help: http://www.wookietranslator.com/

Comment: @randal'thor Haha.. Where did you find this awesome tool?

Comment: @SS-3.14159265358979 A bit of Googling led me to both this tool and an answer to the question!

Comment: Han doesn't understand him perfectly. The novels indicate he speaks good, but not fluent Wookie-speak

Comment: It's likely that Yoda knows at least a little Shyriiwook (or can understand it through the Force somehow) because he was the Jedi on Kashyyyk during Episode III, and there's no sign of an interpreter hanging around in that scene. But since Yoda doesn't directly respond to anything the Wookiees say, I'm leaving this as a comment.

Comment: Are we also including the Star Wars Holiday Special?

Comment: @Richard - Get on the donkey.

Comment: @WadCheber - I'll take that as a "yes".

Comment: Anyone with a Babel Fish in their ear, probably.

Comment: The bigger question is... how did so many people learn so many languages so fast in Star Wars?

Comment: @enderland - I'm guessing they have books on tape, just like the rest of us.

Comment: I mean, how many of us truly understand one another when you get down to it?

Comment: Padmé doesn't. She uses a translator in [Queen's Shadow](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Queen%27s_Shadow)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

### Obi-Wan Kenobi both speaks and understands Shyriiwook.

From the [script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-A-New-Hope.html) for *A New Hope*:

> Ben is standing next to Chewbacca, an eight-foot-tall savage-looking creature [...] He is a two-hundred-year-old Wookiee and a sight to behold.
>
> Ben speaks to the Wookiee, pointing to Luke several times during his conversation and the huge creature suddenly lets out a horrifying laugh. Luke is more than a little bit disconcerted and pretends not to hear the conversation between Ben and the giant Wookiee.

From the [novel](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=HNBjb2dkVFUC&q=ben+talking+to+the+wookie+in+its+own+language&dq=ben+talking+to+the+wookie+in+its+own+language&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CDAQ6AEwAmoVChMIw_yvs_PsyAIVBWsUCh3uTgeq):

> All but old Ben - Ben, who was talking to the Wookiee in its own language, quarreling and hooting softly like a native.

### In *The Force Awakens*, Rey also understands it.

As shown in [this answer from @phantom42 on another site](https://movies.stackexchange.com/a/45185/27759), Rey has at least some understanding of Shyriiwook. Quoting from the novelisation of *The Force Awakens*:

> She tried to find something to say to that, something worthy of the sentiment and the risk they had undertaken. She failed miserably. Chewie, however, had something of his own to add. Whatever the Wookiee had uttered caused tears to well up in her eyes. Having never found himself in such a position before, Finn was unsure how to respond. Knowing well her inner toughness, he wondered what Chewbacca had said that could have inspired such a reaction.
>
> “What’d he say?”
>
> She sniffed and wiped at her face. “That it was your idea.”

---

Less canonically, **[Sabine Wren](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Sabine_Wren)** also speaks [Shyriiwook](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Shyriiwook/Canon) (so presumably understands it too).

> "...it's rough on my throat, I lost my voice for a day after bugging Zeb by serenading him in Shyriiwook."
>   <sub>-- Sabine Wren, *Star Wars Rebels: Sabine, My Rebel Sketchbook*</sub>

Comment: Right!  I forgot that Obi Wan talks to Chewbacca at some length before Chewie introduces him to Han!

Comment: @WadCheber You forgot? Get on the donkey!

Comment: Okay, after you.  Because "Wookiee" is the species, "Shyriiwook" is the language.

Comment: @WadCheber Curses! Better now?

Comment: Much better....

Comment: How about Luke and Lando?  Do they understand Chewie?

Comment: @WadCheber - Discussed in chat. Luke, Lando and Leia don't seem to speak Wookie-speak; http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/25074212#25074212

Comment: “Hooting softly like a native”?!? So I take it Chewie is not a native, then, ’cause there's no way the sounds emerging from his gullet can be described as soft hooting!

Comment: Ahsoka is able to understand Chewbacca in the Clone Wars.

Comment: @JackBNimble - The film or the TV show?

Comment: @Richard The TV show; SE3E22 - *Wookiee Hunt*.

Comment: @TylerH - No good then. Question says "Movies"

Comment: @Richard: true, though the Clone Wars TV series is official canon, so Ahsoka officially understands Chewbacca, even though she was not in the films.

Comment: Rebels is canon.

Comment: @richard - I'm reading *Shadows of the Empire*, which - as you know - is no longer canonical, but it seems pretty clear that Lando is fluent in Shyriiwook.

Comment: Any indication one way or the other for R2-D2?

Comment: @RenegadePrincess Not as far as I know, sorry.

Answer (score 23):

### **Understand Shyriiwook, Master Yoda does**

> When he told them the problem, **the Wookiees nodded and barked at each
> other so fast that it was difficult even for him to follow the
> conversation.** Then they turned and offered him one of their escape
> pods. Yoda accepted at once. The only problem left was how to get past
> the clone troops to the pod.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith - Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_III:_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novel))</sup></sub>

### As does Leia (although not as well as her official profile suggests)

> *“According to her diplomatic profile, Princess Leia speaks both
> Huttese and Shyriiwook fluently. **Regretfully, and as Your Majesty is
> keenly aware, the princess is merely proficient in Shyriiwook.** This
> is, naturally, a failure of mine and not the princess, but I worry
> that such an error might cause her embarrassment. Oh, it is too, too
> humiliating.”*
>
> <sub><sup>[From a Certain Point of View](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/From_a_Certain_Point_of_View) -  [Eclipse](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Eclipse_(short_story))</sup></sub>

---

### Lower canon films

If we also include the [Star Wars Holiday Special](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Star_Wars_Holiday_Special), then we can also add

**Chewie's wife Malla**, **his son Lumpy** and **his father Itchy** as well as **human trader [Saun Dann](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Saun_Dann)**, all of whom demonstrate an ability to understand Chewbacca.

Comment: But this is already stated in the OP. Wad's question is "does anyone ***else*** understand Chewbacca?"

Comment: He said "seems to". I felt it was worth adding a specific confirmation./

Comment: Including the Holiday Special makes me want to undo my upvote.

Comment: Bonus points if you add the fact that the now-noncanonical *Shadows of the Empire* suggests that Lando is fluent in Shyriiwook.

Answer (score 4):

*Note: I don't like getting rep from self-answers, so this is a Community Wiki answer.*

### Legends:

One of the other main characters from episodes V and VI, Lando Calrissian, speaks Shyriiwook well enough to bicker with C-3PO over a translation:

> Chewie said something. Nobody spoke for a moment. Leia said, “Well, is somebody going to tell me what he said?”
>
> Threepio got it out first: “Chewbacca says the woman made him very nervous.”
>
> “He didn’t say ‘very,’” Lando said. “Just plain ‘nervous.’ ”
>
> “Excuse me,” Threepio said. “I inferred the modifier from his tone. Wookieespeak allows for such shadings.”
>
> “You saying my Wookieespeak is bad?” Lando said.
>   -  *Star Wars: Shadows of the Empire*

Throughout this book, Lando shows his proficiency in understanding Shyriiwook on a regular basis.